# How does Kafka message processing scale in publish-subscribe mode?

Tags: apache-kafka

All, Forgive me I am a newbie just beginner of `Kafka`. Currently I was reading the document of `Kafka` about [the difference between traditional message system like `Active MQ` and `Kafka`](https://kafka.apache.org/documentation/#kafka_mq).

As the document put.

For the traditional message system. they can not scale the message processing. 
Since

> Publish-subscribe allows you broadcast data to multiple processes, but
>   has no way of scaling processing since every message goes to every
>   subscriber.

I think this make sense to me.

But for the `Kafka`. Document says the `Kafka` can scale the message processing even in the publish-subscribe mode. (Please correct me if I was wrong. Thanks.)

> The consumer group concept in Kafka generalizes these two concepts. As
>   with a queue the consumer group allows you to divide up processing
>   over a collection of processes (the members of the consumer group). As
>   with publish-subscribe, Kafka allows you to broadcast messages to
>   multiple consumer groups.
>
> The advantage of Kafka's model is that every topic has both these
>   properties—**it can scale processing and is also multi-subscriber**—there
>   is no need to choose one or the other.

So my question is How `Kafka` make it ? I mean scaling the processing in the publish-subscribe mode. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

The main unique features in Kafka that enables scalable pub/sub are:

1. Partitioning individual topics and spreading the active partitions across multiple brokers in the cluster to take advantage of more machines, disks, and cache memory. Producers and consumers often connect to many or all nodes in the cluster, not just a single master node for a given topic/queue.
2. Storing all messages in a sequential commit log and not deleting them when consumed. This leads to more sequential reads and writes, offloads the broker from having to deal with keeping track of different copies of messages, deleting individual messages, handling fragmentation, tracking which consumer has acknowledged consuming which messages.
3. Enabling smart parallel processing of individual consumers and consumer groups in a way that each parallel message stream can come from the distributed partitions mentioned in #1 while offloading the offset management and partition assignment logic onto the clients themselves. Kafka scales with more consumers because the consumers do some of the work (unlike most other pub/sub brokers where the bulk of the work is done in the broker)

Comment: Thanks for review and answer the question. As I knew. The traditional messaging can do the #1 with cluster mode. right? (PS: I am trying to figure out what is the advantage of `Kafka` over the traditional messaging.)

Comment: For #2. If the broker not tracking the message consuming acknowledged . How can `Kafka` make sure the message not being lost during the processing? Thanks.

Comment: No, traditional messaging does not do #1 even in cluster mode. If messages are persistent then traditional messaging stores all the messages in a single master node  (no partitioning) and then replicates the entire message store to other nodes for fault tolerance.

Comment: For #2 the clients are responsible to keep track of their offsets and they can optionally store them back into a special offset tracking topic

Comment: Do mean traditional message system can not make load balance even in the cluster? Only can make High Available ? Thanks.

Comment: They can load balance in a limited way such that one queue is on one node and another queue is on a second node. What they can't do is take a single queue, partition it into pieces, and spread the pieces across multiple nodes (like Kafka does).

Comment: I wrote a whitepaper on this if you are interested https://www.confluent.io/whitepaper/comparing-confluent-platform-with-traditional-messaging-middleware/